# A find condition about hasMany relationship in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I'm working an action for message search in my project,and here are the two models:Msgcontent and Msgblock.Relationship is Msgblock hasMany Msgcontent.What I want to do is get all the Msgblock records that contain Msgcontent with some searching keyword.My code as follows:

```
if($keyword)
{
    $conditions['and'] = array(
                                'Msgcontent.content LIKE'=>'%'.$keyword.'%',
                                'Msgcontent.content <>'=>''
                );
    $results = $this->Msgblock->Msgcontent->find('all',array('group'=>array('Msgblock.chatsessionid'),'conditions'=>$conditions));
}
```

It seems not a good work.Is there any better solution?Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short of writing your own SQL query with appropriate JOINs, this is about the easiest way to do it in Cake with two queries:

```
$ids = $this->Msgblock->Msgcontent->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('Msgcontent.msgblock_id'),
    'recursive' => -1,
    'conditions' => ...
));

$this->Msgblock->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('Msgblock.id' => Set::extract('/Msgcontent/msgblock_id', $ids))
));
```

Comment: I had done it like that,and would cause an error like Unknown column 'Msgcontent.content' in 'where clause'

Comment: @SpawnCxy My bad, the other way around it would work (belongsTo).

Answer (score 1):

You can use bindModel with conditions, Ex:

```
$this->Msgblock->bindModel(
                   array(
                     'hasMany' => array(
                         'Msgcontent' => array(
                            'className' => 'Msgcontent',
                            'conditions' => array(
                                'Msgcontent.content LIKE' => "%$keyword%"
                            )
                         )
                     )
);
```

and then you can use your find without conditions because it's already done when binding.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect situation to use Cake's Containable behavior, as discussed in [multidèria's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10352682/195648) to a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344315/find-conditions-with-hasmany-model).  Either add `Containable` to your Msgcontent model's `$actsAs`, or attach the behavior on the fly.

Answer (score -1):

Setup a sub query in your conditions that searches the hasMany table and returns a count if found.

(select count(id) from YOUR_HAS_MANY_TABLE where YOUR_HAS_MANY_TABLE.foreign_key=MAIN_TABLE.id where YOUR_HAS_MANY_TABLE.field_to_search='%SEARCH%')>0

It is not incredibly efficient but with proper indexing it is a solution that can get the job done.