# CakePHP: How to filter results in the parent model using conditions in the hasMany associations

Tags: php, cakephp, model, cakephp-2.4

CakePHP: 2.4.3

I tried to follow the instructions in the answer for the following question but it applies the condition only in the child models. ([Find conditions with hasMany model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344315/find-conditions-with-hasmany-model))

I want to be able to fetch, for instance, only products that have a ProductsCategory.category_id of say, 2. Right now it only filters the associated models and still returns all of my products.

**EDIT:
Didn't mention it the first time but I'd like to be able to have multiple conditions. ProductsCategory.category_id == 2 AND ProductsTag.tag_id == 1.**

I have these models:
Product, Category and Tag

Product hasMany ProductsCategory and ProductsTag

ProductsCategory and ProductsTag are as follow:

**ProductsCategory**

```
product_id (fk) | category_id (fk)
```

**ProductsTag**

```
product_id (fk) | tag_id (fk)
```

**Model/Product.php** (edited to include suggestion from Rikesh)

```
class Product extends AppModel {
public $primaryKey = 'product_id';

public $actsAs = array('Containable');

public $belongsTo = 'Supplier';
public $hasMany = array(
    'ProductsCategory' => array(
        'className' => 'ProductsCategory',
        'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
        'dependent' => true),
    'ProductsTag' => array(
        'className' => 'ProductsTag',
        'foreignKey' => 'tag_id',
        'dependant' => true
    ));
```

Here's what I've tried to so far:

```
$this->Product->find('all',
            array(
                'recursive' => -1,
                'contain' => array(
                    'ProductsCategory' => array(
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'ProductsCategory.category_id' => 2)
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
```

And

```
$this->Product->find('all',
            array(
                'joins' => array(
                    array(
                        'table' => 'products_categories',
                        'alias' => 'ProductsCategory',
                        'type' => 'inner',
                        'conditions' => array('ProductsCategory.category_id' => 2)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do what I wanted by adding ProductsCategory.product_id = Product.product_id in my joins conditions:

```
$this->Product->find('all', array(
                'joins' => array(
                    array(
                        'table' => 'products_categories',
                        'alias' => 'ProductsCategory',
                        'type' => 'inner',
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'ProductsCategory.product_id = Product.product_id',
                            'ProductsCategory.category_id' => array(2, 3), 
                        )
                    ),
                    array(
                        'table' => 'products_tags',
                        'alias' => 'ProductsTag',
                        'type' => 'inner',
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'ProductsTag.product_id = Product.product_id',
                            'ProductsTag.tag_id' => 1
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Because ProductsCategory belongsTo Product you can find productsCategories and let cake join them with products

```
$this->Product->ProductsCategory->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'ProductsCategory.category_id' => 2,
            'ProductsTag.tag_id' => 1
    ),
        'contain' => array('Product', 'Product.ProductTag'),
        'group' => 'ProductsCategory.product_id'
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked :) I realize I didn't ask for this but would it be possible to search with conditions in multiple associations? For example ProductsCategory.category_id == 2 AND ProductsTag.tag_id == 1?

Comment: I'm getting this: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ProductsTag.tag_id' in 'where clause'. Looking at the query I can see that it is indeed not in the SELECT clause. Note: I fixed the missing s in Product on the 'contain' line.