# can a table have hasMany relation with multiple table

Tags: cakephp

Will the given below code can work where `Mark` and `Subject` are two model with which `Student` model associate through `hasMany` association

```
class Student extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'Student';
    var $hasMany = array(
        'Mark' => array(
            'className' => 'Mark',
            'foreignKey' => 'student_id'
        ),
        'Subject' => array(
            'className' => 'Subject',
            'foreignKey' => 'student_id'
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yes you can relationship with many tables

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

[Find conditions with hasMany model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344315/find-conditions-with-hasmany-model)